# Wordpress: Disable align for core/columns block in theme.json

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to completely disable align (wide and full) options and anchor from columns core block in theme.json. My code now looks like this:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "settings": {
      "blocks": {
          "core/columns":{
            "align": false,
            "anchor: false
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I was trying many things, but nothings works. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible to do with theme.json yet.
[Theme.json reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/theme-json-reference/theme-json-living/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31327585)

Comment: @gremur 
The question is: "Is it possible to do it?"
Carolina's answer is: "No, this is not possible to do with theme.json yet. Theme.json reference"

Carolina provided answer to the question. Short, clear and with link to documantation.